# Creating a Summary Sheet with If Statements in VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba, loops, summary

I have a worksheet with a series of columns as below:

I need to create a summary sheet where I can sum by ID all the "Y" entries so the summary sheet would show a count of Y's per column so the summary sheet would contain C1, C2-C5 with Columns 2-5 being numerical instead of boolean.

I have created a loop to review if the row should be included in the summary (The Date, Region and Job role are all variable as to if they should be included in the summary) I just now need to group and summarise the 4 Y/N columns, I'm just not sure how to do it in VBA as it's not a language familiar to me.

Any help greatly received

ID  Date    Y/N 1   Y/N 2   Y/N 3   Y/N 4   Region 1    Job
1354894 25/06/2017  Y   N   Y   N   South   Sales
1554968 25/07/2016  N   Y   N   Y   North   Admin
4581324 19/08/2017  Y   N   Y   N   East    Admin
4586568 18/06/2016  Y   N   N   Y   South   Admin
4586568 08/11/2017  N   Y   Y   N   East    Sales
4587454 23/04/2016  Y   N   Y   N   North   Sales
4587454 09/12/2017  N   Y   N   Y   North   Sales
4587454 23/08/2016  Y   N   Y   N   East    Sales
4595681 25/06/2017  Y   N   N   Y   West    Sales
5651985 25/07/2016  N   Y   Y   N   West    Sales
5651985 19/08/2017  Y   N   Y   N   South   Admin
5651985 18/06/2016  N   Y   N   Y   South   Admin
5651985 08/11/2017  Y   N   Y   N   East    Admin
7845658 23/04/2016  Y   N   N   Y   East    Sales
7851132 09/12/2017  N   Y   Y   N   South   Sales
7852120 23/08/2016  Y   N   Y   N   South   Sales
9652158 02/08/2017  N   Y   N   Y   North   Sales
9831524 02/09/2017  Y   N   Y   N   West    Admin

Code so far (Without being able to copy and paste)

```
Sub StartSum()

Dim x as long
Dim Startdate as Date
Dim EndDate as Date
Dim Region as String
Dim Role as String
Dim tablerw as long


Startdate = Worksheets("Sheets3").Range("A2")
EndDate =  Worksheets("Sheets3").Range("A4")
Role =  Worksheets("Sheets3").Range("B2")
Region =  Worksheets("Sheets3").Range("C2")

With Worksheets("Sheet1")

x = 2
tablerw = 2
Do While Cells("A").Value <>""

If Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("F" & x).value = Region and     Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("G" & x).value and Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & x).value >= Startdate and Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & x).value <= EndDate Then
 Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & tablerw).Value =  Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & x).Value
 Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B" & tablerw).Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & x).Value
 Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C" & tablerw).Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & x).Value
 Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("D" & tablerw).Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E" & x).Value
 Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("E" & tablerw).Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("F" & x).Value
 Tablerw = Tablerw + 1
 x = x + 1
End If
Next
End Sub
```

I haven't done any summary yet as unsure where to start

Comment: Apologies: I don't know where to start. So Far all I have is the structure as follows:

Comment: Any reason why a pivottable wouldn't sort this?

Comment: It's part of a larger workbook that relies entirely on automation based on the results in one worksheet. This one sheet needs to show a summary of another sheet.

Answer (score 0):

So you are aware of what you could do with a pivottable.

If you set your data, as shown in question, up as a table (Ctrl + T whilst in data range) and add 4 hidden helper columns (I to L) as follows:

[image: pivottable]

Note that the 4 end columns reference your original y/n columns but convert the "Y" to 1 using in `i2` (you would drag this formula across the other columns and the table would autofill down).

```
=--(C2="Y")
```

You could then set the pivottable up to sum these 4 helper columns. Example layout shown above where a summary can be shown by region, date etc.

You could also have your source data as a dynamic named range and point your pivottable at that.

If you are not allowed to show a pivottable consider that you can use [GetPivotData](http://www.contextures.com/xlPivot06.html) formulas to return data from a hidden pivottable to a set up of your specification e.g. a standardized table layout. You can generate pivottables through VBA and target the source to a specified range. Plenty of examples on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Many thanks. Unfortunatley I've been told we can't use a pivot table due to standardisation of tools it has to display in a table with data laid out in a particular way. I've simplified the sheets to ask for help. It's a 20 sheet workbook and the summary fields from the sample above will be providing the data for 4 of 8 columns in a sheet. It needs to populate a summary sheet as on the display sheet the user will have the ability to say the top n ID's which will show the top n based on a column which will be a total of 2 of the columns above.

Comment: 1) You can still display a table and use getpivotdata formulas to pull back the data as per the layout you want. The pivottable being hidden. 2) This means you can also use a slicer to pick top n ID's. (Though i am guessing if you can't show a pivottable then you can't show a slicer).

Comment: I am on mission convert here!

Comment: i may delete this answer so i suggest you add the info above into the question i.e. your top comment under my answer. This will help others with their solutions. Also, look into markdown table generator or some other tool that will allow you to add your sample data in, in a tidy fashion, as it cannot be read easily as currently rendered.